# Permission issue: cannot upload a photo

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error when I try to upload a photo using laravel admin.

> fopen(/var/www/html/public/images/images/6a0f9ab2761ad025e9aa2dc8e57dc3c2.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

I already set my storage's permission as 755, so I changed my public directory's permission but it did not work.

Here's my public directories'info. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root laravel   67 12月 23 00:20 css
drwxr-xr-x 2 root laravel  133 12月 23 00:20 data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root laravel    0 12月 23 00:20 favicon.ico
drwxrwxr-x 3 root laravel   19 12月 23 00:20 images
drwxr-xr-x 7 root laravel   80 12月 23 00:20 img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root laravel 1823 12月 23 00:20 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root laravel 4096 12月 23 00:20 js
drwxr-xr-x 2 root laravel 4096 12月 23 00:20 pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root laravel   24 12月 23 00:20 robots.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      32 12月 23 23:24 storage -> /var/www/html/storage/app/public
drwxr-xr-x 3 root laravel   19 12月 23 00:20 uploads
drwxr-xr-x 4 root laravel   50 12月 23 00:20 vendor
-rw-r--r-- 1 root laravel 1194 12月 23 00:20 web.config
```

Comment: The owner is `root` 755 means only the owner (root) can write. The webserver does not run under root. You should either switch permissions to 777 or change the owner to the webserver user

Comment: never upload user content to the public folder!!!! (O_O)

Comment: And NEVER make it 777!!!! (O_O)

Comment: @apokryfos is correct, change the user, but do NOT change permissions to writable by all!

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, it may be OK to make the permissions 777 when you're developing on a personal machine, but never in production.

Comment: Do you have a folder "images" inside "images" folder?

Comment: i ended up changing the owner, and it worked. thanks for your advice.

Comment: yeah i do not really know why but laravel admin created images inside images, I think I set the setting wrong, but I can fix it later.

Answer (score 0):

You should give folder permission to 777. if you are ubuntu user try " sudo chmod -R 777 /folder-path ".